# Client side paging with $top issue

Tags: javascript, c#, sharepoint-2013

I have these url where I want to apply $top=1000 for side paging as these question: [Sharepoint question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74777/list-api-get-all-items-limited-to-100-rows) but I have I my list catch error when I use it

```
function GalleryContentPopulate(url, listname, target) {

var eng = false;
var queryGallery = "$select=Title,Description,Enlace,EncodedAbsUrl,Categoria/Title&$expand=Categoria/Title";

if ((window.location.href.indexOf("lang=en") > 0)) {
    queryGallery = "$select=TitleEnglish,DescriptionEnglish,Enlace,EncodedAbsUrl,Categoria/English&$expand=Categoria/English";
    eng = true;
}
// Getting our list items
 $.ajax({
    url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items?$top=1000" + queryGallery, 
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {
        completeGalleryContent(data, target, eng);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        failureGalleryContent(data, target);
    }
});
}
```

So how should be my query to works?

Comment: Did you try it with an **&** behind $top=1000

Comment: like `url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items?&$top=1000" + queryGallery` ?